# How to igonre specific number from Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want accept numbers from 0001 to 9999 . It should ignore number 0000.
How can I do it ?
this is for 0000 to 9999 : /^[0-9]{4}$/
Ignore 0000 from this regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but might depend on the engine:

```
^(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), assuming the language you are using supports it:

```
^(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

The `(?!0000)` portion will cause the match to fail right away if the first four characters in the string are zeroes.  Assuming it gets past this point we can continue with the normal `[0-9]{4}` (or `\d{4}`) knowing that '0000' is already excluded.